# How to store datasets in a list in a loop - R

Tags: r, list, loops

Suppose I have dataset A including information on the month ("Date"):

| **station ID** | **precipitation (mm)** | **LONG** | **LAT** | **Date** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 | 5 | 50 | 2010-01 |
| 1 | 60 | 5 | 50 | 2010-02 |
| 1 | 61 | 5 | 50 | 2010-03 |
| 2 | 75 | 10 | 47 | 2010-01 |
| 2 | 65 | 10 | 47 | 2010-02 |
| 2 | 70 | 10 | 47 | 2010-03 |

I have a while loop that creates separate datasets from dataset A based on the month. My aim is to create a list `list_months` that stores all information of each dataset (i.e. month).

```
#used as criterium for selecting data per loop
months = c("2010-01", "2010-02","2010-03")

#used in different variable names, based on month
abr = c("jan", "feb", "mar")

#set item from list to 1 (=January)
i = 1
j = 1
#create empty list to store individual datasets that are generated for each loop
list_months = list()

#while loop. Aim: create 3 separate datasets, based on month, and store each one per loop
while(i <= length(months) && j <= length(abr))
{
  #store each dataset to a different variable name, corresponding to the month
  assign(paste("dataset", abr[j], sep="_"),subset(A, Date == months[i])) 
  
  #assign variable name to variable that is appended to list
  ap <- paste("dataset", abr[j], sep="_")

  #append variable name to list for further data processing
  list_months <- append(list_months, ap)

  #next loop (i.e. following month)
  i = i+1
  j = j+1
}
```

However, when I try to view the first item via `view(list_months[1])` the output is as follows:

|  | **X.dataset_jan.** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dataset_jan |

How can I store the variable name in a list in such a way that it creates the output:

| **station ID** | **precipitation (mm)** | **LONG** | **LAT** | **Date** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 | 5 | 50 | 2010-01 |
| 2 | 75 | 10 | 47 | 2010-01 |

Creating a new list after the loop `list_months = list(dataset_jan, dataset_feb, dataset_mar)` does the trick. However, I would like to store the datasets during each loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is quite strfaightformward using `data.table`'s split

```
library(data.table)
# make sure your data in in a data.table format
setDT(mydata)
# use split.data.table to split on a certain column
split(mydata, by = "Date")
# $`2010-01`
# station_ID precipitation LONG LAT    Date
# 1:          1            70    5  50 2010-01
# 2:          2            75   10  47 2010-01
# 
# $`2010-02`
# station_ID precipitation LONG LAT    Date
# 1:          1            60    5  50 2010-02
# 2:          2            65   10  47 2010-02
# 
# $`2010-03`
# station_ID precipitation LONG LAT    Date
# 1:          1            61    5  50 2010-03
# 2:          2            70   10  47 2010-03
```

Comment: There is no necessity for a data table. A data frame will work just as well.

Comment: I do not agree @dcarlson. As far as I know, on a data.frame you cannot use split without a given factor `f` to split on. So you have to create on, and cannot simply pass a colname. The power of the `split.data.table` here is the `by`-argument, which is not available in split.data.frame.

Comment: without data.table it requires `split(mydata, list(mydata$Date))` so yes it can be done without data.table, however I love the efficiency of data.table as well and surely would favor that instead of the `base::split`