# Create filtered dataframe with dplyr and for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, filter

I want to create several data frames from an original one in R using `for` loop.
I want to get three separated **data frames for each species** to conduct separate analysis.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
data(iris)
library(dplyr)
for i in levels(iris$Species){
  paste0(i,".data") <- data.frame(filter(iris,
                                         Species=="i"))
}
```

I do not necessarily need dplyr but it's the one I am used to.

Comment: Looping isn't necessary or desirable here. You could use the split function in base R.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71573729/6356278

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to keep the separate frames in a list, which as pointed out in the comments is done easily with `split(iris, iris$Species)`

If you really want them out of the list and into separate named frames, you can use

```
list2env(split(iris, iris$Species),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

An even better approach would be to keep everything in one data frame and then use dplyr/tidyr’s `group_by()` and `nest()` functions to fit a model for each group.

See here for a detailed walkthrough: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/nest.html